# Where can I get hold of SPICE guest tools for Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, gnome-boxes, spice

It seems that gnome-boxes requires a package called 'SPICE guest tools' to be installed on a guest system, in order for USB devices to be redirected from the host to the guest. I am running Lubuntu 18.04 as a guest in a gnome box and I am confused as to where I can download this 'guest tools' package.

The gnome-boxes properties dialog window says it can be downloaded from http://www.spice-space.org/download.html ; however, I can only find Windows binaries for the guest tools but not for Linux.

Comment: @guiverc I double-checked and I was mistaken - it's actually 18.04. I will edit my question.

Comment: I have no experience with it sorry, but https://gitlab.com/libosinfo/libosinfo/issues/2 (jbicha) is possibly your answer

Comment: Most likely, you don't need to do anything. `spice-vdagent` is a default package of Ubuntu flavors.

Answer (score 3):

> By now you might have noticed Lubuntu’s screen resolution is small
> with extra black spaces on the left and right side, and folder sharing
> is not enabled too. This brings up the need to install guest tools on
> Lubuntu. ​
>
> Launch terminal program from the guest session (not your
> host terminal program) and install the guest tools using the below
> command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install spice-vdagent spice-webdavd
> ```

[Reference](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/walkthrough-on-how-to-use-gnome-boxes)